# Download file with PhantomJS

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

I'm trying to download a file using `PhantomJS`, but when I click to download, no file is downloaded, I read that `Phantomjs` doesn't support downloads, but I need that, can you help me?

Here's the code from just the part when I try to download:

```
try
{
  checkbox = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("//form[@id='formDownload']//table[@class='fileTables']//tbody//tr//td//input[@class='checkbox']")));      
  checkbox[countLine - 1].Click();      
  wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("all"))).Click();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok what you need to do is:

1. When you clicking on the file in your html you need to find the link of the file.
2. you need to take the link and make httpRequest for getting the file.

Here is full function of the request (i making in easy for you, just find the link)

```
public static bool DownloadFile(string url, IWebDriver driver)
        {
            try
            {
                // Construct HTTP request to get the file
                HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                httpRequest.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

                for (int i = 0; i < driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    System.Net.Cookie ck = new System.Net.Cookie(driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies[i].Name, driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies[i].Value, driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies[i].Path, driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies[i].Domain);
                    httpRequest.CookieContainer.Add(ck);
                }

                httpRequest.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
                httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";

                //HttpStatusCode responseStatus;

                // Get back the HTTP response for web server
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
                Stream httpResponseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();

                // Define buffer and buffer size
                int bufferSize = 1024;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int bytesRead = 0;

                // Read from response and write to file
                FileStream fileStream = File.Create(FilePath + "\\" + FileName + ".xls");
                while ((bytesRead = httpResponseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != 0)
                {
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What if download is session(cookie)-dependent?

Comment: You can see that i handel cookies in my function

Comment: And phantomJS has all the cookies you need.

Comment: `<input id="all" class="button" title="Click to receive the selected files" value="Receive Files" onclick="getAllFiles()" type="button">`

Comment: as you see, when I click to download the file, is executed a javascript function, so I don't know how to get a link in this situation because when I download the file, the download link is the same to any file

Comment: after you click try to inspect your DOM again.it must to be there.

Comment: I inspected the DOM as you said and I saw the js code that get some informations from their database (I think) and submit the form where the file is, after this a generic link is executed, I tried to execute your function with this link but it didn't work, I think it happened because the link is not from the specific file, as I said is a generic link.

Comment: You can post the website link ?

Comment: i understand, try to look how you can find the link. maybe other way.

Comment: I will, I tested this function in a website that show the link of file and it worked, so I know that it works, now I just need to find this link, nevertheless, thank you so much for the attention.

Comment: @JeremiasSantos glad to help

Comment: I'm using WebClient and was having trouble, but adding the UserAgent header made all the difference for me. Didn't think of that... thanks!